# converting Gridview Code to Listview Code

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, gridview

i'm trying to convert a gridview into a listview. The bit that is troubling me is that i can't get at following codes

```
TextBox box1 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(1).FindControl("clientCode");
```

Please help me to achieve this code in Listview Format.

Comment: Why do you need TextBox? To access text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(TextBox)listview1.Items(rowIndex).FindControl("txtFName")
```

This is what you want

Answer (score 0):

You can use ItemCommand event of listview to get the text box control which used in List View control

```
protected void ListView1_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Edit")
        {
            TextBox txtFname = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txtFname");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
TextBox box1 = (TextBox)ListView1.FindControl("clientCode")
```

get text

```
box1.Text = ListView1.SelectedItems[rowIndex].SubItems[1].Text;
```